# How can you detect a third generation iPad 12.9 from previous versions

Tags: ipad, iso

I need to programatically detect the new iPad pro 12.9 inch model in my code and change my interface appropriately. As both the new 12.9 iPads and the old models have the same screen size one can not use that technique to determine which model the app is running on. 
Any Suggestions. 
Thanks
Reza

**Answer:**
For anybody else that might be interested, you need to look at the:

```
ViewController.view.safeAreaInsets
```

the bottom value for the inset is set to 20 for the third generation iPads.

Comment: Sorry, it's zero for me too. Didn't work.

Comment: You have to make the call in viewDidLayoutSubviews() or somewhere after the views have been laid out. viewDidLoad() does not layout the views.

Comment: I am calling it at viewDidLayoutSubviews, still getting 20,0,0,0 (20 is the top)